# How to implement std::find correct?

Tags: c++

I want to search for a string in my vector. I've tried with std::find but everytime the following error appear.

```
54:85: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<Postleitzahl>::vector(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Postleitzahl*, std::vector<Postleitzahl> >)’
   54 |  std::vector<Postleitzahl> it(std::find(plzVector.begin(), plzVector.end(), eingabe));
```

And the red pointer shows to the last ')' of "(...)it(std::find(...), eingabe));"

How can I avoid this error and what triggering it ? 
Here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>



class Postleitzahl
{
    public:
        std::string state;
        std::string zipCode;
        std::string city;
        Postleitzahl(){}
        Postleitzahl(std::string state, std::string zipCode, std::string name);
};

bool fileCheck ()
{
    std::ifstream file("bundesland_plz_ort_de.txt");
    if(!file)
    {
        std::cout << "File could not be opened!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}



int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("bundesland_plz_ort_de.txt");
    Postleitzahl object;
    std::vector<Postleitzahl> plzVector;
    if(fileCheck())
    {   
        while(file >> object.state >> object.zipCode >> object.city)
        {
            plzVector.push_back(object);
        }
        file.close();
    }


    std::string eingabe;
    std::cout << "suche" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> eingabe;
    std::vector<Postleitzahl> it(std::find(plzVector.begin(), plzVector.end(), eingabe));

    //if(it != plzVector.end())
//  {std::cout << "Found: " << *it;

}
```

Comment: You'll need to break this down into more specific questions about each part of your program. This isn't a tutorial-for-order site. You're effectively asking how to write your entire application. I'd wager that your professor has covered much of this in class.

Comment: In the mean time, you're missing a `<<`: `std::cout << plzVector.state[it] << plzVector.city[it] << std::endl;`

Comment: If you don't know how to use the std::find or stl functions, do a simple loop for(const auto& postal : plzVector) { if(postal.zipCode == eingabe) { std::cout << postal.state << postal.city << std::endl; }

Comment: Pop quiz: what type do you think `it` should be? Should it be a full-fledged vector of its own? And if not, why do you declare it as such?

Comment: I really don't know wich type would be ideal. With the vector I tried to avoid the conversion error

Comment: If you look at [some documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) you'll see that it returns an iterator, the same type as its first two parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> std::vector<Postleitzahl> it(std::find(plzVector.begin(), plzVector.end(), eingabe));
> ```

should be:

```
std::vector<Postleitzahl>::iterator it(std::find(plzVector.begin(), plzVector.end(), eingabe));
```

If you have C++11 or above you can use `auto` instead of `std::vector<Postleitzahl>::iterator` and the compiler will deduce the type automatically.